# Why are IE Conditional comments rendered differently when page openned with file:

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I wrote some conditional comments in my html file and opened it with file://path/test.html. It looked fine. I fired up my app server and pointed my IE 8 browser to http://myserver.com/ap/test.html. the results were different. Can anyone explain why this is happening and what might be done about it?

the source

```
<html>   
<body>    
conditional
<p>
<!--[if IE 8 ]>
  <p>Only IE 8 will see this</p>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gt IE 7 ]>
  <p>Only gt IE 7 will see this</p>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE]>
  <p>IE sees this.</p>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if ! IE]>-->
  <p>not IE</p>
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if (gt IE 8)|(!IE)]><!-->
  <p>Every one except IE 8 will see this (gt IE 8)|(!IE)</p>
<!--<![endif]-->

<p>after conditional
</body>   
</html>
```

from opening in file with IE 8:

```
conditional 

Only IE 8 will see this

Only gt IE 7 will see this

IE sees this.

after conditional
```

With same browser in another tab pointing at app server:

```
conditional 

IE sees this.

after conditional
```

My goal is to insert one header on IE 8 browsers and a differetn one on all others. So alternate solutions to that problem would be welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of IE10, conditional comments are [no longer supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx) and should not be used.

For best results, the first line in your page should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`; this will allow older versions of IE to use what used to be called "standards mode" and enable whatever [standards support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699338(v=vs.85).aspx) is available for that particular version of IE.

In general, such tasks are better accomplished using [feature detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh273397(v=vs.85).aspx), rather than browser detection.  Conditional comments were a proprietary feature supported by older versions of IE; code that relies proprietary features tends to break without warning when said feature are no longer supported.

Without a clearer idea of the underlying problem you're trying to solve, it's hard to know what to advise, but given some scenario that absolutely applies only to IE, one that does not have an easier, more elegant solution, here's one way to detect IE8 that doesn't rely on proprietary features:

```
var isIE8 = window.document.documentMode == 8;
```

Unlike conditional comments (which fail when they're not supported), this code will return a value even if the documentMode property isn't available or is removed in some future version of IE.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance